# Filter Bluetooth Devices from ACPI Command Output

Tags: scripting, keyboard, bluetooth, power-management, acpi

I have a battery status script for my laptop which parses the output of `acpi -b`. Since my laptop only has one battery this has worked fine for years.

However, I recently purchased a bluetooth keyboard, and when connected to my laptop the output is now as follows:

```
$ acpi -b
Battery 0: Discharging, 0%, rate information unavailable
Battery 1: Charging, 44%, 00:33:32 until charged
```

Is there any way that I can filter the bluetooth keyboard out, or just stop it from being reconciled by ACPI altogether? (It is a keyboard that uses AAA batteries - it has no charging circuitry so I'm not really sure why it's being reported in the first place).

I know I could just filter out all entries containing "rate information unavailable" but this is obviously a hack, ideally I'd like a solution that can filter out all non-internal devices regardless of their status.

Edit - Both batteries appear in `/sys/class/power_supply`:

```
$ ls /sys/class/power_supply
ACAD  BAT1  hid-34:88:5d:d0:dc:db-battery
```

I don't know how to work out the ID that ACPI assigns from these directories though.

Comment: So this would be best done by first figuring out which out of battery 0 and battery 1 is the internal one, and then using that information to either query with the `acpi` command (I don't know if that's possible) or filter its output, I presume. Unless, of course, `Battery 0` is _always_ going to be the keyboard battery, in which case just filtering the output through `grep -v '^Battery 0:'` would be enough.

Comment: @Kusalananda Unfortunately the labeling of Battery 0 and Battery 1 is not consistent, that was my first thought as well. I have added output of the `/sys/class/power_supply` directory to my question which shows both of the batteries, the missing puzzle piece now is figuring out how to somehow map these back to the ACPI output.